# How to skip over >= in C++

Tags: c++

I can't figure out how to make my code go to the next else if statement if my user input satisfies the previous if state.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double input;
    cout << "Time Calculator\n Enter the number of Seconds: " << endl;
    cin >> input;
    if (input < 60)
    {
        cout << "The time is " << input << " seconds." << endl;
    }
    else if (input >= 60)
    {
        cout << "The time is " << input << " minutes." << endl;
    }
    else if (input >= 3600)
    {
        cout << "The time is " << input << " hours." << endl;
    }
    else if (input >= 86400)
    {
        cout << "The time is " << input << " days." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `input >= 3600 && input< 86400` or `input >= 60 && input <3600`

Comment: Have you understood the purpose of `if`, and `else if`? It's like an either/or check so only one block of code will be executed. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Reverse the order of the conditions, the problem is that, anything >=86400 satisfies all conditions >=60, >=3600 etc..,

Comment: Your title says you want to skip. Your description indicates as though you don't want to skip. Please clarify what behavior you are looking to implement.

Comment: As @SudheeshSinganamalla says, you need to reverse the order of your checks, since the `else` part only happens if the `if` part isn’t true and `input >= 60` will always be checked before `input >= 3600`. You also probably meant to divide `input` by the appropriate number in each case…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, you can implement a check between 2 values using conditions like `>= val1 and < val2` or ensure that the order in which the checks happen is different.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double input;
    cout << "Time Calculator\n Enter the number of Seconds: " << endl;
    cin >> input;
    if (input < 60)
    {
        cout << "The time is " << input << " seconds." << endl;
    }
    else if (input >= 60 && input < 3600)
    {
        cout << "The time is " << input << " minutes." << endl;
    }
    else if (input >= 3600 && input < 86400)
    {
        cout << "The time is " << input << " hours." << endl;
    }
    else if (input >= 86400)
    {
        cout << "The time is " << input << " days." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

or another way would be to change the order, once the particular `if` statement is valid, it doesn't check with the rest of the `if` statements.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double input;
    cout << "Time Calculator\n Enter the number of Seconds: " << endl;
    cin >> input;
    if (input >= 86400)
    {
        cout << "The time is " << input << " seconds." << endl;
    }
    else if (input >= 3600)
    {
        cout << "The time is " << input << " minutes." << endl;
    }
    else if (input >= 60)
    {
        cout << "The time is " << input << " hours." << endl;
    }
    else if (input < 60)
    {
        cout << "The time is " << input << " days." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Logan Glad to hear that it worked. If it helped maybe you could also mark it as an accepted answer. Cheers !

Answer (score 3):

in your code if input > 60 it will satisfy condition and will not execute else part so first check wether input > 86400 if not then check if input > 36000 if not then check for input > 60

try below code in which if conditions are reversed

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
double input;
cout << "Time Calculator\n Enter the number of Seconds: " << endl;
cin >> input;
if (input < 60)
{ 
  cout << "The time is " << input << " seconds." << endl;
}
else if (input >= 86400)
{
    cout << "The time is " << input << " days." << endl;
}
else if (input >= 3600)
{
    cout << "The time is " << input << " hours." << endl;
}
else if (input >= 60)
{
    cout << "The time is " << input << " minutes." << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make it other way round.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double input;
    cout << "Time Calculator\n Enter the number of Seconds: " << endl;
    cin >> input;
    if (input >= 86400)
    {
        cout << "The time is " << input << " days." << endl;
    }
    else if (input >= 3600)
    {
        cout << "The time is " << input << " hours." << endl;
    }
    else if (input >= 60)
    {
        cout << "The time is " << input << " minutes." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The time is " << input << " seconds." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this is what you want!

Comment: The last `else if` could as wel be just an `else`.

Answer (score 0):

Your if else conditions are not completely defined... you have to set those in a range... otherwise is not going to work...

```
if (input < 60)
    {
        cout << "The time is " << input << " seconds." << endl;
    }
    else if (input >= 60 && input < 3600))
    {
        cout << "The time is " << input << " minutes." << endl;
    }
    else if (input >= 3600 && input < 86400))
    {
        cout << "The time is " << input << " hours." << endl;
    }
    else if (input >= 86400)
    {
        cout << "The time is " << input << " days." << endl;
    }
```